# How to programatically set the content of a Viewbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm surprised I can't find this through googling, but I have a Viewbox in a WPF window and I'd like to add a UserControl to it through code. The viewbox is empty, it's simply there to have a "wait spinner" pop up during certain events (I got tired of looking at it on the design view and would just like to stick it in there via code).

I expected there to be something like Viewbox.Content, but no such luck

Comment: ViewBox is not  ContentControl, instead in inherits from Decorator which has a single Child property as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
ViewBox.Child = new BlahMaster2000();
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm not getting any +1's for my BlahMaster2000.

Comment: The +1 you got from me was exclusively for your BlahMaster2000. In fact, I changed the name of my UserControl to BlahMaster2000

Comment: I gave you a +1 for the BlahMaster2000 nomenclature only.